# Calculate the max distance from the mean for array of datapoints and return relevant datapoint

Tags: javascript, arrays

Assuming I have an array of data as follows:

```
var data = [{name: "craig", value: 10}, {name: "oliver", value: 15}]
```

I would like to use a function that allows parameters such as:

```
function separateTheWheatFromTheChaff(windowSize, pointsTaken, data, valueAccessor) {}
```

Where windowSize is the number of array positions to be evaluated, pointsTaken is the number of dataPoints to be returned.

So I know I'll need the sum from which to gain the mean. I will need to calculate the math.abs for each array position in relation to the mean and compare each result to find the datapoint array position furthest from the mean and then return that original datapoint value to a new array.

So far I have:

```
var data = [{name: "craig", value: 10}, {name: "oliver", value: -10}]

function separateTheWheatFromTheChaff(windowSize, pointsTaken, data, valueAccessor) {    
    var i;
    sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < windowSize; i++) {
        sum += valueAccessor(data[i]);
    }
    mean = sum/windowSize   
    for (i = 0; i < windowSize; i++) {
        Math.abs(valueAccessor(data[i]) - mean)
    }
} 

separateTheWheatFromTheChaff(5, 1, data, function(item) { return item.value });
```

> So my question is, how would I need to amend the
>   separateTheWheatFromTheChaff function to calculate the array position
>   with the data point furthest from the mean, and return said datapoint
>   to a new array.

Thanks in advance, and I hope that makes sense.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? You haven't really asked a question.

Comment: I have added a block quote to clear up the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

**EDITED ANSWER:**

```
//create an array to store all distances
var distances = []; 
for (i = 0; i < windowSize; i++) {
    //calculate distance from mean
    var distance = Math.abs(valueAccessor(data[i]) - mean);
    //store initial datapoint with its distance from mean in array
    var datapoint_w_distance = {datapoint: data[i], 
                                dist: distance}
    distances.push(datapoint_w_distance)
}
//sort array so datapoint with largest distance from mean is first
distances.sort(function(a,b) {return b.dist-a.dist});
//use the pointsTaken parameter to get the correct number of original datapoints back
var wheat = [];
for (var j=0; j < pointsTaken; j++) {
   wheat.push(distances[j].datapoint)
}
return wheat;
```

For example, if

```
var data = [{name: "a", value: 20}, 
            {name: "b", value: 10},
            {name: "c", value: 90},
            {name: "d", value: 100},
            {name: "e", value: 0}]
```

then `separateTheWheatFromTheChaff(5, 2, data, function(item) { return item.value })` returns the array `[{name: "d", value: 100}, {name: "c", value: 90}]`

**Working fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ubbrx3u3/5/

Comment: @Hicki I've edited my answer to fit what I believe you're looking for and so that you can get multiple datapoints back.